# Dynamical variables in a quantum oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, harmonic-oscillator

Can someone please explain how we get the first equality (1.118)? (Here $\omega_p$ is the frequency of the quantum harmonic oscillator, whose 'dynamical variable' is $q_p$)

[image]

Comment: I love this book. You need to prove it in the Heisenberg picture using the Heisenberg equations of motion for the dynamical variables. Refer to page 7 of the book, and of course remember the Hamiltonian for the harmonic oscillator.

Comment: But what exactly do you mean by q_p? Is it related to the position and momentum operators? It cannot be the ladder operator as it's not hermitian. I've tried to prove it using the Heisenberg picture but I cannot obtain the 2w_p in the denominator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you're looking for the correlation function of the ground state of the quantum harmonic oscillator between some time $t_2 - t_1$, to be specific. Let $t_2 = T$ and $t_1 = 0$ to make the algebra simpler. The Hamiltonian is:

$$ \hat H = \frac{\hat p^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2 \hat q^2,$$

Let $m = 1$. The solution to the Heisenberg equations of motion for the dynamical variables $\hat q(t)$ is:

$$ \hat q(t) = \hat q\cos \omega t + \hat p\frac{\sin\omega t}{\omega} $$

Then the expression to be evaluated is
$$ \langle 0|\hat q(T)\hat q(0)|0 \rangle = \langle 0|\hat q^2|0 \rangle\cos\omega T + \langle 0 | \hat p\hat q | 0\rangle \frac{\sin\omega T}{\omega}$$

The matrix elements on the RHS can be easily evaluated using expansions in terms of creation and annihilation operators (use commutation relations to obtain the second term's evaluation):

$$ \langle 0 | \hat q ^2 | 0 \rangle = \frac{\hbar}{2\omega}, \quad \langle 0 | \hat p\hat q | 0\rangle = -\frac{i\hbar}{2}$$

Therefore the final expression is (setting $\hbar = 1$):

$$ \langle 0|\hat q(T)\hat q(0)|0 \rangle = \frac{1}{2\omega}e^{-i\omega T}$$